# Autodiscover Issues with Exchange Managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am using the Exchange Managed API in C# to access Exchange 2010.  I am having issues with using the Autodiscoverurl function.  I have tried a number of different methods with various different errors:

Code:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Autodiscoverurl("email@domain.com", delegate { return true; });
```

Error:

> The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.

Code:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Autodiscoverurl("email@domain.com");
```

Error:

> Autodiscover blocked a potentially insecure redirection to
>   https:// servername /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml.  To allow
>   Autodiscover to follow the redirection, use the
>   AutodiscoverUlr(string, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback)
>   overload.

Code:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Url = new Uri("https://servername/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
```

Error:

> The request failed.  The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.

I have tried various ways of providing credentials, all with the same results as above.

```
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
etc.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever manage to find a solution for this ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I worked around it by attempting to use the autodiscover and then fall back to a set URL if it fails.

Comment: As is customary on StackOverflow, you can answer your own question with the solution that worked for you! I am sure it will help out some future visitors. :)

Comment: what kind of license are you using? I had some issues with  Exchange Online Kiosk type. I've posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21462278/exchange-api-and-asp-netthe-request-failedthe-remote-name-could-not-be-resolve/23208042#23208042

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the autodiscover xml requires credentials, if Basic doesn't work NTLM is usually more reliable.