# Exchange API and ASP.NET:the request failed:the remote name could not be resolved:"server name"

Tags: asp.net, exchangewebservices

so when clicking the submit button in my application to create appointment on outlook
calling the function SendOutLookAppointment()
i get the error  on this line  appointment.Save();
 The request failed. The remote name could not be resolved:'servername'

```
 public static void SendOutLookAppointment()
    {

        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
        service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin@test.com.", "password");
        service.AutodiscoverUrl("admin@test.com");

        ImpersonatedUserId i = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "admin@test.com");
        service.ImpersonatedUserId = i;

        Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
        appointment.Subject = "Calendar booking via WebService";
        appointment.Body = "this is a test";
        appointment.Start = new DateTime(2014, 02, 03, 21, 0, 0);
        appointment.End = new DateTime(2014, 02, 02, 22, 0, 0);

        appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add("me@test.com");

        appointment.Save();
    }
```

Comment: `service.AutodiscoverUrl("admin@@test.com");` stands out as clearly wrong, as it's not a valid URL (or a valid email address for that matter).

Comment: hi sorry it appears so when editing here on the forum to hide the real  email address.Am i suppose to be using a URL there instead? If so which one?  the example on msdn has an email adress at that place service.AutodiscoverUrl("user1@contoso.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

Comment: Using an email address is the correct usage, as it should look up the email server using DNS records. Make sure your DNS records correctly have your MX records etc.

Comment: Please help me understand as I am not an Exchange server guy. I can send emails with no problem from asp.net application with using the same account  but its only when starting to use the web service that the error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, the problem was different licenses.  License: "Exchange Online Kiosk" specifies: "Direct access to Kiosk user mailboxes via Exchange Web Services is not permitted."
You can check differences between various license types here: http://www.office365advisors.com/exchange-licensing/